# Autostart (BOOT_COMPLETED) does not work on the Nomi tablet

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

My broadcast receiver triggered by event BOOT_COMPLETED and works fine on many devices except Nomi C10103. 
The message appears in the log on the device:
*D/ActivityManager: send broadcast: android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED, skip package: com.example.myPackageName*

Sending message *am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED com.example.myPackageName* from adb shell also does not run the application.

Manifest code:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".AutoRunReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

AutorunReceiver.java:

```
public class AutoRunReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //приёмник автозагрузки
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
            final String msg="intent:"+intent+" action:"+intent.getAction();
            Log.d("myLogs",msg);
            Toast.makeText(context,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the `<category>` tag in the `<intent-filter>`? That doesn't belong there. You should remove that in any case. Maybe it will solve this problem.

Comment: I find this tag in the intent-filter of DrWeb manifest (this app starts fine on this device after reboot). Removing this tag has no effect.

Comment: On some devices there is an extra security setting where the user needs to specifically permit applications to be launched at boot, or to run in the background. Perhaps this device has such a security setting. Look through the settings screens to see if you see a list of apps that are allowed to run in the background or run at boot.

Comment: There are no such settings on my device

Comment: Havbe you started the app on the device before rebooting? Does your app have an `Activity` and have you manually started that `Activity` at least once before booting?

Comment: To @DavidWasser. Yes, I started app before rebooting.

Comment: Have you "force stopped" the app before rebooting?

Comment: No, I have no stopped the app before rebooting.

Comment: Then I have run out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: Sending message *am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED com.example.myPackageName* from adb shell also does not run the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized that the problem is not in the code, but the device itself. Autoplay not working on my tablet for any application. As a workaround I have used the event *"android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"*, which is triggered after the device loading and screen unlocking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

its working fine for me.if its lenovo mobile you should wait at least 2 minutes then it will open automatically.